# Shading HikariCP into jar won't work

Tags: java, maven, jar, minecraft, bukkit

Now this seems so weird, that it shouldn't happen. Anyways, let me explain what's going on:
I'm making a bukkit plugin which happens to need database access. For that, I'm using HikariCP. I've used it before in several project and I should have no issues with it, but something really weird just happened. After adding it as dependency to my pom and configured the shade plugin to shade it, I built the jar. I even checked its contents by using Winrar to unarchive it, and it all looked as it should. However, as soon as I loaded it, I got the NoClassDefFound exception. I'll provide the pom here if that helps you, but as I said, the final jar looks fine. Also, if you're not familiar with Bukkit and the way it handles plugins, it's pretty simple. It basically has a folder where you place your jars (plugins). It then scans through it and then loads the main class of your plugin (which is defined in a yml file in the jar and must extend JavaPlugin) and then calls the `onEnable()` method inside the main class.

EDIT: Forgot to add the pom, here it is: http://hastebin.com/rapijoyona.xml
Also, if you need the stack trace: http://hastebin.com/owazutekum.go

Answer (score 1):

You must define what should be shaded.

```
<execution>       
    <phase>package</phase>
    <goals>
        <goal>shade</goal>
    </goals>
    <configuration>
        <shadedArtifactId>${project.artifactId}-${minecraft.version}</shadedArtifactId>
        <shadedArtifactAttached>true</shadedArtifactAttached>
        <shadedClassifierName>shaded</shadedClassifierName>
        <minimizeJar>true</minimizeJar>
        <!-- INCLUDE SHADE-->
        <artifactSet>              
            <includes>
                <include>groupId:artifactId</include>
            </includes> 
        </artifactSet>          
    </configuration>        
</execution>
```

And yes, I read what you wrote, but try it maybe this works better

Comment: Thank you, but I can't actually verify it now. I have absolutely no idea what was causing this, but it was apparently solved by changing the version of HikariCP to an older one (I don't remember exactly which). The strange thing is that after that I tried reverting to the latest version of hikari and it still worked, as if nothing ever happened. Since then, I couldn't reproduce the issue and to this day I have no idea what on earth caused that to happen. I only know it drove me mad.